# AWS Service discovery, nginx and node issue

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, service-discovery, aws-fargate

I am running 2 services in AWS ECS fargate. One is with nginx containers running behind the application load balancer. And the other is running with a node.js application. Node application is running with service discovery and Nginx containers proxy to the "service discovery endpoint" of node application containers.

My issue is :
After scaling up node application containers from 1 to 2. Nginx is unable to send the requests to the newly spawned container. It only sends the request to old containers. After restart/redploy of nginx containers it is able to send the requests to new containers.

I tried with "0" DNS ttl for service discovery endpoint. But facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx does not resolve resolve at runtime if your server is specified as part of an upstream group or in certain other situations, see [this SF post](https://serverfault.com/questions/638505/nginx-dynamic-proxy-pass-doesnt-resolve-properly) for more details. This means that Nginx never becomes aware of new containers being registered for service discovery.

You haven't posted your Nginx config so it's hard to say what you can do there. For proxy_pass directives, some people suggest using variables to force runtime resolution.

Another idea might be to expose a http endpoint from the Nginx container that listens to connections and reloads Nginx config. This endpoint can then be triggered by a lambda when new containers are registered (Lambda is in it's turn triggered by CloudWatch events). Disclaimer: I haven't tried this in practice, but it might work.